# UnsupportedOperationException when using RetryableTopic

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, opentracing

I have an issue with using the RetryableTopic together with the opentracing springboot functionality. The RetryableTopic definition looks like this:

```
   @RetryableTopic(
      attempts = "3",
      backoff = @Backoff(delay = 3000, multiplier = 2.0),
      topicSuffixingStrategy = TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_DELAY_VALUE,
      kafkaTemplate = "dltKafkaTemplate",
      listenerContainerFactory = "retryEventListenerFactory",
      exclude = {
          DeserializationException.class,
          SerializationException.class,
          MessageConversionException.class,
          ConversionException.class,
          MethodArgumentResolutionException.class,
          NoSuchMethodException.class,
          ClassCastException.class
      }
  )
  @KafkaListener(
      topics = "dlt-msg-test-topic",
      containerFactory = "retryEventListenerFactory")
  public void consume(
      String message, @Headers MessageHeaders messageHeaders) {
    LOGGER.info("Received {}", message);
    throw new RuntimeException("Test retry exception");
  }

  @DltHandler
  public void dlt(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
    LOGGER.info(in + " from " + topic);
  }
```

This sample works fine by itself, triggers the retries and dlt. As soon as I try to add the tracing functionality to the project by introducing opentracing-spring-cloud-starter for example and related dependencies then the following error is thrown:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This implementation doesn't support this method
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory.getConfigurationProperties(ProducerFactory.java:120)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.determineSendTimeout(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:661)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.verifySendResult(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:636)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.publish(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:628)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.send(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:524)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.sendOrThrow(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:489)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.accept(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:461)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.FailedRecordProcessor.getRecoveryStrategy(FailedRecordProcessor.java:181)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleRemaining(DefaultErrorHandler.java:134)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2674)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2555)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2429)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2307)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1981)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1365)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1356)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1251)
```

After debugging, I have found that the opentracing creates a wrapper around the original consumer that is called TracingKafkaConsumer. This TracingKafkaConsumer stores the original consumer as one of it fields. So when the DefaultErrorHandler is called as part of retry cycle instead of original consumer the TracingKafkaConsumer is passed into the handleRemaining method of DefaultErrorHandler.

If i understand correctly, after that the SeekUtils.seekOrRecover fails with exception because it cannot detect the necessary parameters from the original consumer like it would when running without the tracing functionality. My guess is that those parameters cannot be found because the original consumer is now a field within the TracingKafkaConsumer and hence that seek functionality that fails doesn't know how to get the things it needs from the original consumer.

My question is, how can I get out of this situation and have both TracingKafkaConsumer and RetryableTopic functionality working correctly together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like open tracing wraps the `ProducerFactory` in another factory (that, presumably, wraps the producers in the tracing producers).

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This implementation doesn't support this method
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory.getConfigurationProperties(ProducerFactory.java:120)
```

The producer factory wrapper should implement `getConfigurationProperties()` and call the delegate factory to get its properties.

I suggest you open a bug against open tracing to fix their wrapper so that it implements all the necessary methods by delegating to the real factory.

That said, all we are trying to do here is determine the send timeout setting on the producer.

Please open an issue here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues we can be a bit more tolerant if the producer factory doesn't honor the contract, and fall back to some default timeout.

**EDIT**

It looks like they already fixed it...

https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-kafka-client/blob/31ce5260279c2cadf3d69c0acbd50f024afe4660/opentracing-kafka-spring/src/main/java/io/opentracing/contrib/kafka/spring/TracingProducerFactory.java#L121-L124

They fixed it a couple of years ago; you must be using an old version

https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-kafka-client/pull/87

https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-kafka-client/commit/31ce5260279c2cadf3d69c0acbd50f024afe4660

**EDIT2**

Well, it was fixed in 2021, but it looks like there hasn't been a release since 2020.

Maybe that project is dead?

Comment: thank you for replying. I have seen this issue and left a comment there about the version that could be used but no reply so far. In case the project is dead, this means to fix this I would need to either 1) fork the code of the iib and release a version myself or 2) switch to a different tracing lib. In the second case, is there a tracing library spring provides that definitely works with RetryTopic?

Comment: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-sleuth - in the next major release (Boot 3.0, Spring 6.0), we are moving to micrometer tracing. I still don't mind making spring-kafka more forgiving, if that will help you.

Comment: thx will have a look at sleuth. it would be useful if spring-kafka would be a bit more lenient. i will try to open an issue in the link you have provided. maybe it will lead to something. once again thx for helping

Answer (score 0):

OpenTelemetry is the merging of OpenCensus and OpenTracing into a single project:

https://opentelemetry.io/docs/migration/opentracing/
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).