spring-kafka 2.7.0 | Using @RetryableTopic causing listener to go into infinite loop when exception occurs
spring-kafka 2.7.0
Using @RetryableTopic causing listener to go into infinite loop when exception occurs
Retry logic is working as it should. But they seem to be reading the same message infinitely while pushing to the correct topics.
Tried playing with the commented lines in the config. but didn't work.
KafkaConfiguration.java
@Configuration
//@EnableKafkaRetryTopic
@EnableKafka
@Slf4j
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "kafka.config.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
public class KafkaConfiguration {
  
  @Autowired
  ReformerKafkaProperties kafkaProperties;
  
  @Bean
  public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    configProps.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE, Object.class);
    configProps.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
  }
  
  @Bean
  public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
  }

  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> consumerProps = new HashMap<>();
    consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
//    consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
//    consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1000);
    consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getConsumerGroup());
    consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    consumerProps.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE, Object.class);
    consumerProps.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProps);
  }

  @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
//    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.RECORD);
//    factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(0L, 0)));
    return factory;
  }

}

AsyncReformationKafkaListener.java
@Slf4j
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "kafka.config.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
public class AsyncReformationKafkaListener {

  @RetryableTopic(
      backoff = @Backoff(value = 30000),
      attempts = "3",
      autoCreateTopics = "true",
      include = RuntimeException.class)
  @KafkaListener(
      topics = "${kafka.config.async-topic}", 
      groupId = "${kafka.config.consumer-group}")
  public void executeReformation(String messageString, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
    log.info("Kafka msg at topic {}", topic);
    throw new RuntimeException();
  }

}

Only one message was produced on reformer-async-local. It got duplicated exponentially on retry topics
a13400412@MAC-a13400412 bin % sh kafka-get-offsets.sh --bootstrap-server=localhost:9092 --topic=reformer-async-local-retry-1
reformer-async-local-retry-1:0:1492
a13400412@MAC-a13400412 bin % sh kafka-get-offsets.sh --bootstrap-server=localhost:9092 --topic=reformer-async-local-retry-0
reformer-async-local-retry-0:0:175
a13400412@MAC-a13400412 bin % sh kafka-get-offsets.sh --bootstrap-server=localhost:9092 --topic=reformer-async-local        
reformer-async-local:0:1
a13400412@MAC-a13400412 bin % 


That Spring for Apache Kafka version even out if Commercial Support: https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support. Consider to upgrade to something more modern. Your problem might be fixed. Or do you talk about Spring Boot version?

@ArtemBilan found the root of the problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73894535/unsupportedoperationexception-when-using-retryabletopic
Seems like need to upgrade
But the problem is since 3.x Java 11 is not working anymore. so would require java upgrade as well

upgrade to spring-kafka 2.8.11 fixed it
